# VSCode run default launch configuration for currently selected directory

Tags: visual-studio-code

I usually work in workspaces, where each JIRA task = separate workspace. In that workspace, I add multiple services (different repos).

I am using VSCode launch configurations to launch those services.

If I press F5 (start debugging), it will always select one service, independent of whatever file is currently open.

Usually, I am modifying some file and want to restart the service that this file is corresponding to.

How can I make F5 local to current sub-folder inside of workspace?